# IBM Queue manager connection failing with below error

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect via `CA DevTest tool`. It is failing with below error. I am unable to find what could be the reason. can someone suggest?

```
Unexpected error: java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider: Provider com.ibm.mq.jmqi.CustomCharsetProvider not a subtype
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider: Provider com.ibm.mq.jmqi.CustomCharsetProvider not a subtype
```

Comment: What version of the MQ Client jar files are you using?  Are you pointing to the full `java/lib` of the MQ Client install location?

Comment: i am using com.ibm.mq.jmqi-7.5.jar

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, point the classpath to the java/lib directory of the original IBM MQ install location which contains ALL required jar files.

---

See my answer to "[IBM MQ Java Error :: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.internal.MQCommonServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843293/ibm-mq-java-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-ibm-mq-internal-mqcom/43853920#43853920)" for more details.